# Combine two lists while removing duplicates

Tags: ocaml

The goal is to combine (append) two lists while removing the duplicates.

```
let rec find_dup a lst =
  match lst with
    | [] -> false
    | hd::tl -> if (hd == a) then true else find_dup a tl;;

let rec app lst2 lst1 =
  match lst1 with
    | [] -> lst2
    | hd::tl -> if (find_dup hd lst2) then (app tl lst2)
     else hd::app tl lst2
     ;;
```

I have my code like this but when the test case is
`app [4;5;6;7] [1;2;3;4]` the answer should be `[1;2;3;4;5;6;7]`
but I keep getting

```
 - : int list = [1; 2; 5; 3; 6; 4; 7]
```

What is going on?

Comment: Please don't alter the question in ways that invalidate existing answers. I've reverted the changes, so no action needed on your part, but please don't do it again.

Comment: Small nitpick: `==` should be `=` and `if (hd == a) then true else find_dup a tl` => `hd = a || find_dup a tl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're switching the lists around for every recursive call.

Look at the argument order of the function definition:

```
let rec app lst2 lst1
```

and then the recursive function call:

```
app tl lst2
```

Also, just to nitpick, `find_dup` already exists in the standard library. It's called `List.mem`.

Comment: Thank You, so I should not make the app a recursive function? but have it inside?

Comment: No, it should be recursive. But you shouldn't swap the order of arguments when you call it. The fix is, therefore, to swap them back.

Answer (score 0):

We can see what glennsl is talking about if we trace out your example.

```
app [4; 5; 6; 7] [1; 2; 3; 4]
  find_dup 1 [4; 5; 6; 7] -> false
  1 :: app [2; 3; 4] [4; 5; 6; 7]
    find_up 4 [2; 3; 4] -> true
    1 :: app [5; 6; 7] [2; 3; 4]
      find_up 2 [5; 6; 7] -> false
      1 :: 2 :: app [3; 4] [5; 6; 7]
        find_up 5 [3; 4] -> false
        1 :: 2 :: 5 :: app [6; 7] [3; 4]
          find_up 3 [6; 7] -> false
          1 :: 2 :: 5 :: 3 :: app [4] [6; 7]
            find_up 6 [4] -> false
            1 :: 2 :: 5 :: 3 :: 6 :: app [7] [4]
              find_dup 4 [7] -> false
              1 :: 2 :: 5 :: 3 :: 6 :: 4 :: app [] [7]
                find_dup 7 [] -> false
                1 :: 2 :: 5 :: 3 :: 6 :: 4 :: 7 :: app [] []
                  [1; 2; 5; 3; 6; 4; 7]
```

If we get rid of the reversal of lists:

```
let rec find_dup a lst =
  match lst with
  | [] -> false
  | hd::tl -> hd = a || find_dup a tl

let rec app lst1 lst2 =
  match lst1 with
  | [] -> lst2
  | hd::tl -> 
      if find_dup hd lst2 then app tl lst2
      else hd :: app tl lst2
```

Now:

```
app [4; 5; 6; 7] [1; 2; 3; 4]
  find_dup 4 [1; 2; 3; 4] -> true
  app [5; 6; 7] [1; 2; 3; 4]
    find_dup 5 [1; 2; 3; 4] -> false
    5 :: app [6; 7] [1; 2; 3; 4]
      find_dup 6 [1; 2; 3; 4] -> false
      5 :: 6 :: app [7] [1; 2; 3; 4]
        find_dup 7 [1; 2; 3; 4]
        5 :: 6 :: 7 :: app [] [1; 2; 3; 4]
          5 :: 6 :: 5 :: [1; 2; 3; 4]
          [5; 6; 7; 1; 2; 3; 4]
```

Of course, this is inefficient, as we have a loop (`find_dup`) within a loop (`app`) meaning this has quadratic runtime complexity. We can do better.

Let's just append both lists and then sort the whole. We'd get:

```
[1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7]
```

The sorting is O(n * log n), and concatenating the lists is O(n). Removing duplicates them is an O(n) operation.

```
# let[@tail_mod_cons] rec uniq = function
    | ([] | [_]) as lst -> lst
    | a::(b::_ as tl) when a = b -> uniq tl
    | a :: tl -> a :: uniq tl;;
val uniq : 'a list -> 'a list = <fun>
# uniq [1; 2; 3; 4; 4; 5; 6; 7];;
- : int list = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7]
```